# Is there a (official) p2 repository for the Google Guava library?

Tags: guava, p2

I've used the Google Guava library for a half year now inside some small Eclipse RCP applications. Until now it's worked well with the older versions of Guava 11/12 provided inside the Eclipse Orbit p2 repositories.

In a new project I need to use Base64 encoding, but this feature only exists in Guava since version 14, which is not available inside Eclipse orbit.

I know that there is an alternative within the Apache commons, but I want to have minimal dependencies to other bundles.

I also know the bundle itself is OSGi compatible, but the classic RCP build based on features and it is a good practice to define a feature based target platform.

So does somebody know an (official) p2 repository that includes the latest guava version, or do I need to build my own feature based on the library?

Comment: Seems like the [discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/guava-discuss) might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: Is building your own p2 repository with the Guava bundle an option?

Comment: @Paul: Yes thats right, sometimes it is better to read to the end of a text.

Comment: @oberlies Yes that is an option, but I was hoping to be able to work around this.

Comment: IMHO having a feature containing Guava is a follow-up question that could be omitted here. Concise questions are more useful for future visitors (with problems of reading to the end ;-), so users are more motivated to answer concise questions.